# Get start date and end date of current week (week start from monday and end with sunday )

Tags: javascript, date

I want to display start date and end date of current week. (week start=monday, week end=sunday)
I manage to display monday.

But I'm unable to get sunday date.
Please post me if anyone has solution.

Comment: what's your code for "getting monday" ?

Answer (score 33):

```
<script>
Date.prototype.getWeek = function(start)
{
        //Calcing the starting point
    start = start || 0;
    var today = new Date(this.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = today.getDay() - start;
    var date = today.getDate() - day;

        // Grabbing Start/End Dates
    var StartDate = new Date(today.setDate(date));
    var EndDate = new Date(today.setDate(date + 6));
    return [StartDate, EndDate];
}

// test code
var Dates = new Date().getWeek();
alert(Dates[0].toLocaleDateString() + ' to '+ Dates[1].toLocaleDateString())
</script>
```

I believe this works.

Comment: @user725184, if you have found the answer satisfactory, please accept the answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more.

Comment: A bit nasty as it needlessly changes the date object's time and date.

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where the start and end date are in different months.

Comment: Just try to print start date and end date today you will get wrong answer.It returns 30th aug as start Date and  5th aug as end date.That is the case where start and end date are of different month it gives wrong answer.

Answer (score 15):

The following function will do the trick:

```
// return an array of date objects for start (monday)
// and end (sunday) of week based on supplied 
// date object or current date
function startAndEndOfWeek(date) {

  // If no date object supplied, use current date
  // Copy date so don't modify supplied date
  var now = date? new Date(date) : new Date();

  // set time to some convenient value
  now.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  // Get the previous Monday
  var monday = new Date(now);
  monday.setDate(monday.getDate() - monday.getDay() + 1);

  // Get next Sunday
  var sunday = new Date(now);
  sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - sunday.getDay() + 7);

  // Return array of date objects
  return [monday, sunday];
}

// Mon Nov 12 2012 00:00:00
// Sun Nov 18 2012 00:00:00
alert(startAndEndOfWeek(new Date(2012,10,14)).join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
var current = new Date();     // get current date    
var weekstart = current.getDate() - current.getDay() +1;    
var weekend = weekstart + 6;       // end day is the first day + 6 
var monday = new Date(current.setDate(weekstart));  
var sunday = new Date(current.setDate(weekend));
```

Comment: @habib -Can you please explain with what date it is not working?

Comment: @Habib: Because for today 28-Sep-2016 it is working fine and this week is in the overlapping months.

Comment: Perfect Solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

`SetDate` will sets the day of the month. Using `setDate` during start and end of the month, will result in  wrong week

```
var curr = new Date("08-Jul-2014"); // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)); // 06-Jul-2014
var lastday = new Date(firstday .setDate(last)); // 12-Jul-2014
```

If setting Date is 01-Jul-2014, it will show firstday as 29-Jun-2014 and **lastday as 05-Jun-2014 instead of 05-Jul-2014**. So to overcome this issue I used

```
var curr = new Date();
day = curr.getDay();
firstday = new Date(curr.getTime() - 60*60*24* day*1000); // will return firstday (i.e. Sunday) of the week
lastday = new Date(firstday.getTime() + 60 * 60 *24 * 6 * 1000); // adding (60*60*6*24*1000) means adding six days to the firstday which results in lastday (Saturday) of the week
```

Comment: The only one solution here who handle all specials cases, thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the other examples you will have a problem when sunday falls in other month.
This should solve the problem:

```
var today, todayNumber, mondayNumber, sundayNumber, monday, sunday;
    today = new Date();
    todayNumber = today.getDay();
    mondayNumber = 1 - todayNumber;
    sundayNumber = 7 - todayNumber;
    monday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+mondayNumber);
    sunday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+sundayNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on RobG's answer, I ended up with this to get week to start on midnight Monday and end on Sunday 23:59:59.999.

```
  var weekMap = [6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  function startAndEndOfWeek(date) {
    var now = new Date(date);
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var monday = new Date(now);
    monday.setDate(monday.getDate() - weekMap[monday.getDay()]);
    var sunday = new Date(now);
    sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - weekMap[sunday.getDay()] + 6);
    sunday.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    return [monday, sunday];
  }
```

Comment: this one is perfect for all the scenarios

Comment: We are using it in CouchDB list functions to aggregate sums per week for documents with timestamps, and it seems to work quite well so far.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly Modified answer of @ReadWriteCode, this also works successfully with different months.

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function()
{
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var date = today.getDate() - day;

        // Grabbing Start/End Dates
    var StartDate = new Date();
    var EndDate = new Date();
    StartDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); EndDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    StartDate.setDate(today.getDate()-day);
    EndDate.setDate(today.getDate()-day+6);
    return {
        startDate:StartDate,
        endDate: EndDate
    };
} 
var thisWeekDates=new Date().getWeek();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using https://momentjs.com makes it more simple.

1. To get week **starting with Sunday and ending with Saturday**, 
   then use: moment().startOf("week").toDate() and 
   moment().endOf("week").toDate()
2. To get week **starting with Monday and ending with Sunday**, 
   then use: moment().startOf("isoWeek").toDate() and moment().endOf("isoWeek").toDate()

Tried this on moment v2.18.1, it works.

Hope this helps, for more you can refer moment docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the return value to meet your needs, right now it just returns the full object of Sunday.

```
Date.prototype.endWeek=function(){
  return new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(),(7-this.getDay())+this.getDate());
}

//call like this
var myDate = new Date(); 
var Sunday = myDate.endWeek();
alert("Sunday falls on "+ Sunday.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you :

```
Date.prototype.getWeekEndDate = function () {
    diff = 6 - this.getDay();
    if (diff < 0) {
        diff += 6;
    }
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + (1 * diff));
    return this;
}
Date.prototype.getWeekStartDate = function () {
    diff = this.getDay() - 6;
    if (diff < 0) {
        diff += 7;
    }
    return this.setDate(this.getDate() + (-1 * diff));
}
```

These method will return start date and end date of the week.

Answer (score 0):

1. Different months issues is also fixed with below code.
2. Added format "M.dd.yyyy" function.

   function startAndEndOfWeek(setDate) 
   {
       var day = null; var date = null;var month = null;var year = null;
       var mon = null; var tue = null; var wed = null; var thu = null; var fri = null; var sat = null; var sun = null;

   ```
   var now = setDate ? new Date(setDate) : new Date();
   now.setHours(0,0,0,0);

   var monday = new Date(now); var tuesday = new Date(now); var wednesday = new Date(now); var thursday = new Date(now);
   var friday = new Date(now); var saturday = new Date(now); var sunday = new Date(now); 

   if(new Date(now).getDay() == 0)
   {
       monday.setDate(monday.getDate() - 6);
       tuesday.setDate(tuesday.getDate() - 5);
       wednesday.setDate(wednesday.getDate() - 4);
       thursday.setDate(thursday.getDate() - 3);
       friday.setDate(friday.getDate() - 2);
       saturday.setDate(saturday.getDate() - 1);
       sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - 0);
   }
   else
   {
       monday.setDate(monday.getDate() - monday.getDay() + 1);
       tuesday.setDate(tuesday.getDate() - tuesday.getDay() + 2);
       wednesday.setDate(wednesday.getDate() - wednesday.getDay() + 3);
       thursday.setDate(thursday.getDate() - thursday.getDay() + 4);
       friday.setDate(friday.getDate() - friday.getDay() + 5);
       saturday.setDate(saturday.getDate() - saturday.getDay() + 6);
       sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - sunday.getDay() + 7);
   }

   date = monday.getDate();
   month = monday.getMonth();
   year = monday.getFullYear();
   mon = getMonthValue(month) + "." + getDateValue(date) + "." +  year;

   date = tuesday.getDate();
   month = tuesday.getMonth();
   year = tuesday.getFullYear();
   tue = getMonthValue(month) + "." + getDateValue(date) + "." +  year;

   date = wednesday.getDate();
   month = wednesday.getMonth();
   year = wednesday.getFullYear();
   wed = getMonthValue(month) + "." + getDateValue(date) + "." +  year;

   date = thursday.getDate();
   month = thursday.getMonth();
   year = thursday.getFullYear();
   thu = getMonthValue(month) + "." + getDateValue(date) + "." +  year;

   date = friday.getDate();
   month = friday.getMonth();
   year = friday.getFullYear();
   fri = getMonthValue(month) + "." + getDateValue(date) + "." +  year;

   date = saturday.getDate();
   month = saturday.getMonth();
   year = saturday.getFullYear();
   sat = getMonthValue(month) + "." + getDateValue(date) + "." +  year;

   date = sunday.getDate();
   month = sunday.getMonth();
   year = sunday.getFullYear();
   sun = getMonthValue(month) + "." + getDateValue(date) + "." +  year;

   return [mon, tue , wed, thu, fri, sat, sun];
   ```

   }

   function getMonthValue(month)
   {
       switch(month)
       {
           case 0: return "Jan";
                   break;
           case 1: return "Feb";
                   break;
           case 2: return "Mar";
                   break;
           case 3: return "Apr";
                   break;
           case 4: return "May";
                   break;
           case 5: return "Jun";
                   break;
           case 6: return "Jul";
                   break;
           case 7: return "Aug";
                   break;
           case 8: return "Sep";
                   break;
           case 9: return "Oct";
                   break;
           case 10: return "Nov";
                   break;
           case 11: return "Dec";
                   break;
       }
   }
   function getDateValue(day)
   {
       if(parseInt(day) < 10)
       {
           return "0" + day;
       }
       return day;
   }

Answer (score 0):

as in [this link](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-51.php)

```
function endOfWeek(date)
  {

    var lastday = date.getDate() - (date.getDay() - 1) + 6;
    return new Date(date.setDate(lastday));

  }

dt = new Date(); 

console.log(endOfWeek(dt).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure vanilla JS. no third party libraries. Returns Sunday to Sunday 00am.

```js
const now = new Date()
const startOfWeek = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - now.getDay())
const endOfWeek = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), startOfWeek.getDate() + 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check code snippet for week start from monday to sunday

```
const curr = new Date(); // get current date
const currentWeekDay = curr.getDay();
const lessDays = currentWeekDay === 0 ? 6 : currentWeekDay - 1; // handle sunday to monday week start day
const wkStart = new Date(new Date(curr).setDate(curr.getDate() - lessDays));
const wkEnd = new Date(new Date(wkStart).setDate(wkStart.getDate() + 6));
```