# Get the most recently occurring Sunday

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to display the current week in a calendar view, starting from Sunday.

What's the safest way to determine "last sunday"  in Javascript?

I was calculating it using the following code:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(n) {
      return new Date(this.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000)*n);
}

var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var lastSunday = today.addDays(0-today.getDay());
```

This code makes the assumption that every day consists of twenty four hours. This is correct, EXCEPT if it's a daylight savings crossover day, in which case the day could be twenty-three or twenty-five hours.

This week, In Sydney, Australia, we set our clocks forward an hour. As a result, my code calculates `lastSunday` as 23:00 on Saturday.

So what IS the safest and most efficient way to determine last Sunday?

Comment: A very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381427/get-start-date-and-end-date-of-current-week-week-start-from-monday-and-end-with?rq=1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To safely add exactly one day, use:

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
```

which is daylight saving safe. To set a date object to the last Sunday:

```
function setToLastSunday(d) {
  return d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay());
}
```

Or to return a new Date object for last Sunday:

```
function getLastSunday(d) {
  var t = new Date(d);
  t.setDate(t.getDate() - t.getDay());
  return t;
}
```

#### Edit

The original answer had an incorrect version adding time, that does add one day but not how the OP wants.

Comment: What if the last sunday was in a previous month? (e.g. it's the first day of the month and a Thursday) Edit: It appears the date API gladly accepts offsets. Nice

Comment: Zirak—Date methods happly convert invalid date values to date objects, e.g. `new Date(2012,1,30)` becomes 2012-03-01 and `new Date(2012,1,0)` becomes 2012-01-31. That can be handy, or a trap for new players. :-)

Comment: @Zirak—an interesting note is that `new Date('2012-02-30')` returns `Invalid Date` in FF, but IE and Chrome return a date object for `2012-03-01`. More reasons not to trust the Date function to parse strings (though all modern browsers correctly return `NaN` if the string is passed to [`Date.parse`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2)).

Comment: Why do you need this line: `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);` for daylight saving? It gives the next sunday instead of past sunday if today is Saturday.

Comment: @Shawn—that's just an example of how to add a day that is "daylight saving safe", e.g. the day going into daylight saving is only 23 hours long, so adding 24 hours to a date for 23:30 on the previous day will be 00:30 on the day after tomorrow, not 23:30 the following day. Adding 1 to the date returns the correct "tomorrow" with a time of 23:30.

Comment: This last Sunday function returns the same date if the day is now Sunday.

Comment: @massanishi— the algorithm in the answer is the one the OP wanted. If you want the previous Sunday if today is Sunday, then use `t.setDate(t.getDate() - (t.getDay() || 7))`.

Comment: I would also generally recommend against using the world `last` because it is ambiguous between "previous" and "final".

Answer (score 12):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUFMz/1/)

It uses only built in date methods

```
var now = new Date();
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var lastSunday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-today.getDay()));
```

Answer (score 2):

using `date-fn` library: `previousSunday(date)`

```
const now = new Date(); // the date to start counting from
previousSunday(now);
```

Docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/previousSunday