# October 4th to October 5th 2012 has one extra hour in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Here is what I have discovered.
In 2012 October 4th at midnight to October 5th at midnight has 25 hours. 
perhaps in some part of the world there is a dst that i don't know about?

when you call javascripts innate getTime:
-in both IE and Mozilla.
- This is while still on client side. 
There are normally 86400 seconds in a day and the difference between the 5th and 4th of October is 90000 even (one additional hour)
-only fails for 2012 . -> 07/05/2011 – 10/05/2011 works…2012 it does not.
-07/04/2012 – 10/04/2012 works.

this is an excerpt of code.the elements are strings in the format "mm/dd/yyyy"

```
    var fromDateElement = document.getElementById("filterFromDate");
    var toDateElement = document.getElementById("filterToDate");



    if (fromDateElement == null || fromDateElement.value == ""
         || toDateElement == null || toDateElement.value == "") {
        alert(dojoCallGetLocalizedMessage("please.enter.filter.dates"));
        return false;
    }
    var fromArr = fromDateElement.value.split("/");
    var toArr = toDateElement.value.split("/");
    var timeSpread = (new Date(toArr[2],toArr[0],toArr[1]).getTime()) - 
            (new Date(fromArr[2],fromArr[0],fromArr[1]).getTime());
    if (timeSpread >  <%= ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS %>) {
alert(dojoCallGetLocalizedMessage("not.a.day"));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

(one day in millis is set to 864000000)
Additionally there is logic to take in dst but not in october

Comment: Can you print `new Date().toString()` for both dates? It'll say which time zone it uses.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791378/get-the-most-recently-occurring-sunday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, months are numbered from `0` (January) to `11` (December) — see [the MDN page for `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) — so month #`10` is November, not October. You need to subtract `1` from your month-number:

```
    var timeSpread = (new Date(toArr[2],toArr[0]-1,toArr[1]).getTime()) - 
            (new Date(fromArr[2],fromArr[0]-1,fromArr[1]).getTime());
```

**Edited to add** for the benefit of any non-U.S. readers: on November 4th, 2012, most parts of the U.S. will "fall back" from Daylight Saving Time: at what would otherwise be 2:00 AM, the clock gets set back to 1:00 AM. So that day is actually 25 hours long.

Comment: Thank you. figured it was a dst related thing.
Ben franklin you caused a lot of problems

Comment: @user555075: You're welcome! And yeah, I've been dealing with some painful DST stuff at work this week, so I totally know what you mean. :-P